# Simple math app: answer always equals 1

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to programming so this is probably a result of my illiteracy, but I would appreciate a solution anyways. 
I'm trying to make an app that takes the user input from 12 different textfields and feeds out an answer into a label by mathematically altering the user input using Cramer's rule.

So far, I've been trying to multiply the user input from one textfield by the user input from another and feed it out into a label, but whenever I type in my numbers, the product is always 1, and it doesn't print to the label.

Here is my code:

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  Cramer


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

// Objects are given addresses:


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *box_a;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *box_b;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *hiLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *clickButton;

@end
```

AND

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Cramer


#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Math takes place:

- (IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender {

    NSInteger number1 = [self.box_a.text integerValue];
    NSInteger number2 = [self.box_b.text integerValue];

    NSInteger prod = number1 * number2;

    self.hiLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(prod)];

}

@end
```

Thanks

Comment: The first thing to do is set a breakpoint in `clickButton` and make sure that `self.box_a`, `self.box_b` and `self.hiLabel` are not nil.  Also your stringWithFormat` should be `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",prod];`

Comment: @Paulw11: I agree with your first advice. But the `stringWithFormat` line seems to be fine, `prod` is "boxed" into an `NSNumber` object.

Comment: You would be better off using `NSNumberFormatter` to parse strings  into `NSNumber`s from user input.

Comment: Yes, they have boxed an NSInteger into an NSNumber, incurring an object creation and then a call to description method - or they could just use %ld

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that you have control dragged from your button and called it an outlet, but then in the .m file you have referred to it as an action.  Delete the connection to the button as an outlet, and then reinstall it as an action.

Comment: @user3587655, Did you figure out what was going on?  Did you get your App to work?  Don't get discouraged by down votes.  People on this site want to see what you have tried before giving assistance.  You might want to do some of the basic tutorials out there to get a better understanding of Obj-C and programming.  A great place to start is Apple's site and Ray Wenderlich's site on tutorials.  You tube has many as well like Geeky Lemon Drop.  Just do some searches on topics you want to learn about.  This community is one of the best and once you get the hang of if, you will love it!

Answer (score 0):

Use `%ld` as the format specifier in the last statement:

```
self.hiLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", prod];
```